# How to install elasticsearch-migration plugin in windows?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I tried using the following command to install the elasticsearch-migration plugin in windows:

```
/bin/plugin -i elastic/elasticsearch-migration
```

i got the error "The syst cannot find the path specified" even though it's the right path. Then i tried in the bin directory:

```
plugin -i elastic/elasticsearch-migration
```

it said "plugin is not recognized as an internal or external command.. "
How do i install it in windows?

Answer (score 1):

You need to cd into your Elasticsearch installation folder and then run `plugin.bat` (and without the initial slash) because the `plugin` one (without extension) is for *nix systems.

```
.\bin\plugin.bat -i elastic/elasticsearch-migration
```

Comment: Now it's showing bin is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: what if you first `cd bin`and then run `plugin.bat ...`?

Comment: Then i tried:  plugin.bat  install elastic/elasticsearch-migration   It showed "-> Installing elastic/elasticsearch-migration...
Trying https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-migration/archive/master.zip ...
ERROR: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get detailed information"

Comment: I directly downloaded it from the given path : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-migration/archive/master.zip  . But wanted to know why it failed to download using the command.

Comment: Can you now try to run `plugin.bat -i elastic/elasticsearch-migration --url file:///path/to/elasticsearch-migration.zip`, i.e. pointing directly at the downloaded file?

Comment: It's still showing plugin.bat not an internal or ext command, operable command or batch file.

Comment: how about `.\plugin.bat -i ...`?

Comment: Same error..I tried : `plugin.bat -i elastic/elasticsearch-migration`  inside bin folder.This time it worked. I don't know why it didn't work in the beginning. Thanks anyway :)